# Can I get 4 screens running on an ATI Radeon HD 5700 series video card?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, amd-radeon

I have successfully run 3 displays using the 5700, but i want to run a 4th screen off the HDMI Port. Mainly I would like it to Mirror the primary monitor onto the TV connected to the HDMI Port. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. I can get a signal to it, i just have to disable one of my original 3 monitors. Im not willing to do that. So other than disabling one of my monitors, does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The ATI Radeon 5700-series cards only support 3 displays at once.

From [AMD/ATI's 5750 specs page](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-5000/hd-5750/Pages/ati-radeon-hd-5750-overview.aspx#2):

> ATI Eyefinity multi-display technology
>
> - Three independent display controllers
> - Drive three displays simultaneously with independent resolutions, refresh
>     rates, color controls, and video
>     overlays

Comment: There has to be a way to at least mirror one of the 3 "independent displays" on the HDMI output. I know that they have Radeons capable of driving 6 displays at once, from a single card.

Comment: It's just impossible. It is not able to drive more than three displays, no matter what is displayed. Try searching for a hdmi repeater which doubles the outputs

Comment: @Wayne - No, it's not possible.  The base chipset doesn't support this, although there are a few OEM variants of the chipset that do.  See, for example, this 5770 which can push all four outputs at once because they hacked another display controller onto it (although it only supports single-link DVI on one of the ports :/) http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814102906

Comment: @Wayne - There are indeed Radeons that will drive up to six displays from a single card.  This Is Not One Of Them™.

Comment: If i added a second Card in CrossFireX  would i be able to run another "3 Independent Displays" or would there still be limitations. Technically that should give me 3 more outputs. Or am i wrong about this?

Comment: @Wayne - I'm not 100% sure on the current generation but in the past, when in CrossFire mode, it intentionally limits the amount of monitors that can be enabled, so that the horsepower drives them 'faster' instead of using it on extra monitors.  If you installed a 2nd card with CrossFire _disabled_ you should be able to run 6 monitors.  If you're just looking to add a 4th, low usage monitor, perhaps check out DisplayLink-compatible products for easy-to-use, cheaper alternatives (see http://www.displaylink.com/shop/index.php?product=5)

Comment: @Wayne - No problem, if my answer is good, perhaps accept it as such. Helps both our rep. scores. ;)